# insert query with ajax without reloading whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to insert data through AJAX (without reload page). I tried but it is not showing data and also reload page.

I have a file **first.php** (in which, form is present), a AJAX code and a **firstcall.php** where query will be execute.

My **first.php** (html form) is:

```
<form  class="reservation-form mb-0" action="" method="post"  autocomplete="off">
<input name="name1" id="name1" class="form-control"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" required aria-required="true">
<input name="age" id="age" class="form-control" required  type="number" placeholder="Enter Age" aria-required="true">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="namec[]" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" >
<input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-warning" value="Submit" id="submit">
 </form>
```

Here data should be display:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
 <div class="panel panel-primary" id="showdata">

</div>      
</div>
```

AJAX is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(){
    var name1 = $("#name1").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();

    var chkArray=[];
    $('.checkbox1:checked').each( function() {               
    chkArray.push($(this).val());    
    } );
    var selected;
    selected = chkArray.join(',') ;

    if(selected.length > 1){
    $.ajax( {
    url:'firstcall.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{name1: name1,age: age,namec: chkArray},
     }).done(function(data){
      $("#showdata").html(data);
         });

        }
            else{
    alert("Please at least one of the checkbox");   
 }
 }  
 }  

</script>
```

**firstcall.php** is:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" id="showdata">
<?php 
foreach($_POST['namec'] as $selected){
echo $selected;
$_SESSION['name1']=$_POST["name1"];
$_SESSION['age']=$_POST["age"];

echo $name1=$_SESSION['name1'];
echo $age=$_SESSION['age'];

$query=mysql_query("insert into patient_details (p_name,p_age,g_number) values ('$name1','$age','$selected')") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: First, change your `submit` button type to `button`, because submit will automaticaly reload the page!

Comment: The page is reloading because the of submit button , try to change it to simple button and then post data to the php file.

Comment: Unless you `preventDefault()`

Comment: Yes, another issue, I think in `firstcall.php` there should be only one `echo` ate the end of the script ?

Comment: Thankyou for reply. I changed type button. But now, if I click then no action performed.

Comment: @vinodjaiswal, in your `firstcall.php`, try comment all the code and leave a simple `echo('Hi, its firstcall.php');` and see if this message will show in `#showdata`, because i think there should be only one `echo` in the php file!

Comment: Tried. But no action.

Comment: chech `)` abd `}` at the end of the js script

Comment: Oh. thanx, J.Litvak...Now its working. But If reload manually then result disappeared. How can I prevent them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `$("#submit").click(function(event){` add command

```
event.preventDefault();
```

And your page will not be reloaded

Comment: that was a quick issue spotting

Comment: Did you insert `event` in `$("#submit").click(function(event){` ?

Comment: No, it is in header.

Comment: In footer.php ?

Comment: just before footer

Comment: Can we connect with teamviewer please?

Answer (score 1):

The submit button will automatically reload the page on click so the solution is either change the button type to `button` or add `preventDefault` to the click event

```js
$("#submit1,#submit2").click(function() {
  alert('form submited')
})
$("#submit3").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('form submited')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  this will reload the page
  <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-warning" value="Submit" id="submit1">
</form>

<form>
  this will not reload the page
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit2">
</form>


<form>
  this will not reload the page
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit3">
</form>
```

Comment: thank u for reply... But still I have a problem..If I reload manually browser, then result shown by ajax is disappeared. How can I prevent the results?